# How to show output from Executor Service from java controller to views?

Tags: java, executorservice

I have ajax call to a function call "submit"
the submit function is also run executor service for "doStuff" function.

it's return "ok" successfully in ajax complete condition, but I need to show the output from the executor service to the views when the process is finish.
Is there any way to show the output of "doStuff" function ?

Try to return x inside "doStuff" function but it show an error

```
//views  AJAX CALL
$("#formInput").submit(function (e) {
    $("#submitFile").html("<i class='fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin'></i> Load..").prop("disabled", true);
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "${local_server}/UploadController/submit",
      data: new FormData(this),
      processData: !1,
      contentType: !1,
      cache: !1,
      dataType: "json",
      
      complete: function (e) {
          console.log(e);
          if (e.responseText=="ok"){
           //do();
          }
      }
    });
    
    e.preventDefault();
  });


//Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/submit", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
    public @ResponseBody String submitSurvey1(@ModelAttribute("uploadForm") UploadTest uploadForm, Model map,
            HttpSession session, HttpServletRequest request) {
        
        executor.submit(() -> doStuff(uploadForm,map,session,request));     // how I show this func output to views
        return "ok";  // it's already return ok 
        

    }

 private void doStuff(@ModelAttribute("uploadForm") UploadTest uploadForm, Model map,
                HttpSession session, HttpServletRequest request){
         
         token.regenToken(session);
            String x = "";
            
                                JSONObject hit = new JSONObject();
                                hit.put("pathfile", "path");
                                hit.put("filename", "filename");
                                hit.put("submitted_by", session.getAttribute("session_id").toString());

                                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(new RestServiceUnirest().requestPost(
                                        this.API + "/SubmissionLimit/uploadrecord/ec",
                                        session.getAttribute("accesskey").toString(), hit.toString()));

                                x = json.toString();   //How I show this x in output

                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                file.delete();
                                x = e.getMessage();
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }

            }
         
     }
```